# What is the meaning of these Fixed Point Properties e.g.CustomSectionInputDataType?

Tags: matlab, filter-design, butterworth, fixed-point

I was trying tom implement a Butterworth filter and i came across a example on Mathworks site which emphasizes to customize various terms related to the filter.
Following are some of the terms i could not understand and i was also not able to find suitable  info about them in matlab documentation-

1.CustomScaleValuesDataType
2.SectionInputDataType
3.CustomSectionInputDataType
4.SectionOutputDataType
5.CustomSectionOutputDataType

Can anyone please help me to understand this?

This was the link i was referring to-
https://in.mathworks.com/help/hdlfilter/examples/hdl-butterworth-filter.html

Comment: That's for fixed-point implementations. Have a look at [this page](https://nl.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/armcortexm/ug/fixed-point-property-settings-for-dsp-biquadfilter-system-object.html).

Comment: Hi @MattL. the page gives how to implement these specs.Sorry but i could not see the link you attached gives info on these parameters.These specs are already present on the link which i have attached in the question.

Comment: Try again, the link should work. It explains these parameters. They are about the fixed-point number formats (Q15, Q31).

Comment: Hi @MattL. , sorry i am not able to get you,the link describes how these are used in Q15 and Q31 formats. I am asking what is the meaning of these parameters in filter design?